# javascript: unable to figure out the error!

Tags: javascript, html

Below is a script written in JavaScript, the purpose is to take a sentence from input and that should be split into array of words eliminating white space. Every piece of word should be further split into 2 or 3 lettered depending on the size of word ignoring remaining letters in it.

If the said word is greater that 1 and less than 5 or if it is greater than 6 the it should be four letter word. The output of all words should be joined with an underscore in between.

Below is the code that is not working and I am unable to figure it out. Please guide me to make it work

```
document.getElementById("cliename").onchange = function(event){
var list_cname = new Array();
var cname = document.submit.cliename.value;
list_cname = cname.split(" ");
var list_len = list_cname.length;
var valu;
var final_valu;
var i=0;

for (i=0;i<=list_len;i++){ 
        var sub_list = list_cname[i];
        var sub_list_len = sub_list.length;
        if(sub_list_len>=1 && sub_list_len<=5 ){
            sub_list_len=sub_list_len-1;
            }
            else if(sub_list_len>=6 ){
                    sub_list_len=4;
                }
        var list_val = list_cname[i].substring(0,sub_list_len);
        valu = list_val;
        final_valu = valu + "_" + final_valu;  
    }
    document.write("list -" + cname + ", len - " + list_len + ", final " + final_valu);
}
```

The error i get that is "SUB_LIST" is UNDEFINED.

Comment: What is not working? Add an error to the question, we can't read minds here...

Comment: the error is "SUB_LIST" is UNDEFINED.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, change

```
for (i=0;i<=list_len;i++)
```

to

```
for (i=0;i<list_len;i++)
```

or `list_cname[i]` will index out of bounds.

Comment: thank you that was the error by removing "=" the problem was solved tanks a ton.

Answer (score 1):

From a rough look at your code, without knowing the errors, etc..

You're referencing:  `sub_list_len` but that's not a length.

You would need to do something like:

`sub_list_len.length`

or

`var sub_list_len = sub_list.length`

Comment: it was removed accidently. Sorry that was removed for checking purpose if so i have replaced the same the error i get that is "SUB_LIST" is UNDEFINED.

Answer (score 1):

I've made some changes to your code and put an example up on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mJxmZ/). Also pasted below

```
document.getElementById("cliename").onchange = function(event){
    var list_cname = [];
    var cname = this.value;
    list_cname = cname.split(" ");
    var list_len = list_cname.length;
    var valu = "";
    var final_valu = "";
    var i=0;
    for (i=0;i<=(list_len-1);i++)
    {
        var sub_list = list_cname[i];
        var sub_list_len = sub_list.length;

        if(sub_list_len > 1 && sub_list_len <= 5 )
        {
            sub_list_len = sub_list_len-1;
        }
        else if(sub_list_len>=6 )
        {
            sub_list_len = 4;
        }

        var list_val = list_cname[i].substring(0,sub_list_len);
        valu = list_val;
        final_valu = valu + "_" + final_valu;
    }
    document.write("list - \"" + cname + "\", len - " + list_len + ", final " + final_valu);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var list_cname = new Array();
var cname = document.getElementById('cliename').value;
list_cname = cname.split(" ");

var list_len = list_cname.length;
var valu;
var final_valu;
var i = 0;

for (i = 0; i <= list_len; i++) {
  alert();
  var sub_list = list_cname[i];
  var sub_list_len = sub_list;
  if (sub_list_len >= 1 && sub_list_len <= 5) {
    sub_list_len = sub_list_len - 1;
  } else if (sub_list_len >= 6) {
    sub_list_len = 4;
  }
  var list_val = list_cname[i].substring(0, sub_list_len);
  valu = list_val;
  final_valu = valu + "_" + final_valu;
}

alert("list -" + cname + ", len - " + list_len + ", final " + final_valu);
```

```html
<input type='text' id='cliename' value='1 2 3' />
```